# Are questions concerning Apache Spark Mllib approach to cross validation acceptable on CV?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have been reading on cross validation and wanted to experiment with Apache Spark's Mllib. I tried to read the provided material ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/ml-guide.html)) but it is still very unintuitive and unclear to me how it works when using `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` classifier.

I would say I have a conceptual understanding of the cross validation topic and would need a little more help in understanding. I was wondering where the correct space is to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about how Apache Spark Mllib works, what code / functions / packages to use, error messages, etc. would almost certainly be off topic here. Questions about how cross validation, logistic regression, etc. would almost certainly be on topic here. It depends on what you want to know. Note that the former might be on topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) if they are coding questions & include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for people to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I guess I will ask about cross validation in here and for technical details in the stack overflow. Thank you again.